# Is it possible to create an intelligent chatbot using tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, android-studio-2.3

I have done research on how to create a chatbot that is capable of machine learning. My first prototype was based on using dialogflow, however, there was certain issues that I faced that did not allow the chatbot to be capable of machine learning. (I.e Dialogflow doesn't allow the bot to store previous user's queries to be use for future queries.) I also found out that when faced with a question that it has never seen before, Dialogflow does not have the capability to store/create new training phrases from the new question automatically. Based on my results with Dialogflow, I did my research about Tensorflow and found out that it is capable machine learning and deep learning which could potentially solve my problem.

Comment: It is possible, but if you have to ask this question then it is far above your level of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

[A neural chatbot using sequence to sequence model with attentional decoder.](https://github.com/chiphuyen/stanford-tensorflow-tutorials/tree/master/assignments/chatbot)

This is a fully functional chatbot with Tensorflow.